# Implementation of FANOUT using Toffoli gates

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

Consider the following implementation of FANOUT using Toffoli gates:

[image]

I'm confused about the following statement: "the second bit being the input to the FANOUT and the other two bits standard ancilla states". **Does it mean that the second bit is also the input to the other two ancilla states? Why do ancilla states require any inputs, aren't they pre-determined?**

Comment: Each post should be focused on one question. Also, since the value of a question to the community depends on other people's ability to find it, please avoid using images for text.

Comment: @user1271772 just a heads up: editing questions automatically throws them out of the review queue. That means that making trivial edits to a question can effectively be used to single-handedly override other people's close votes. For this reason, please refrain from making edits from the review queue that don't directly address the reason the question is in the queue. I'm all for correcting grammar etc, but this is a case in which it's better not to

Comment: @glS that's not correct, unless something changed 2 days ago when the review queue system got changed. But my edit was longer ago.

Comment: @user1271772 what are you saying isn't correct exactly? An edit throws a question out of the review queue. You can also see it directly in the timeline of this post, for example. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162034/276202

Comment: @glS I'm driving, ping me if I don't reply in 3 days.

Comment: @glS Thanks for waiting. I'm not exactly sure what happened here. The question was in the close-vote queue and it was asking 2 questions instead of 1, which is against our policy. However [I believe](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/457/2293) that in order to retain potentially excellent users, we need to be a bit more friendly about "closing" their questions, as I for one would rather be given the chance to improve my question rather than to have it closed then deleted by Roomba. Usually I'd reduce the post to a single question and let the user know in the comments, but

Comment: maybe I was on my phone and it would be too difficult to properly do that edit without risking introducing errors. I did see a fairly bad faux-pas in the first line which may have been attracting downvotes yet could easily be fixed, so I fixed that. If people are concerned about their close votes being cancelled when a high-rep user improves typos, one solution I like very much is to encourage close voters to iron out all grammar, spelling, typographical, formatting and incorrect-tag issues before injecting the user's question with the close-vote poison. If you're going to VTC, then be fair.

Comment: @Alexia. As Adam correctly pointed out, we have a policy of one question per post. I have commented out your second question, so that you don't ever have to retype it if you do choose to ask it in a separate post :)    glS: If you see the edit I just made now, this is what I usually do when I edit questions like these, and I think that's the extent to which people should improve questions before VTC. This way we're not just doing something that most users would perceive to be a negative action (voting to close) but also **we are being helpful to the user** and also avoiding future VTC edits.

Comment: @user1271772 that's fine, I agree with making edits to fix questions and avoid them getting closed. I was just pointing out that trivial edits which do not significantly fix the issues of a question are better avoided in these specific instances, as you might not have known that these edits throw questions out of the queue.. which is good, as long as they actually do fix the reason the question got in the queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Does it mean that the second bit is also the input to the other two ancilla states?"

Nothing is "input to the ancilla states". The second bit in this case, is the input to the FANOUT, whereas the first and third bits are ancillas.

> "Why do ancilla states require any ***inputs***, aren't they ***pre-determined***?"

In the diagram that you posted, the ancilla qubits are ***pre-determined*** to have ***inputs*** of 1 and 0 respectively.